# How and why the state of free particle in quantum physics is represented by plane wave packet?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, s-matrix-theory, scattering-cross-section, asymptotics, plane-wave

In Quantum Mechanics (Cohen Tannoudji)  Topic: *"Asymptotic Form Of Stationary Scattering States"*

It is written that for large negative values of $t$,  the incident particle is free and it's state is represented by plane wave packet! How and why is the state of free particle in quantum physics represented by plane wave packet?

Comment: Can  you explain what you would like clarified?  Why a particle can be represented by a superposition of plane waves?  *How* the superposition creates a wave packet?  (I'm not as smart as Cohen-Tannoudji, but I would think that a stationary scattering state would be a *plane wave* not a packet of them.)

Comment: I want to know how a free particle is described by a plane wave ?

Answer (score 1):

> How and why the state of free particle in quantum physics is represented by plane wave packet

In quantum field theory ,interacting particles are represented by solutions of the appropriate quantum  mechanical equations in the well known and successful  Feynman diagrams.

A free particle should be the solution of the appropriate quantum mechanical equation without a potential, i.e. a plane wave. BUT plane waves cannot be used as probability functions because they extend from minus infinity to plus infinity, which means the particle will have equal probability to be anywhere in space time.  To have a wavefunction for a localized particle  the [wave-packet](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/wpack.html) solution is used

[image: wavepacket]

Fortunately QFT  developed and does not need this complexity to describe particle  *interactions.*